# Python import statement. ModuleNotFoundError: when running tests and referencing a module in a parent folder

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam, aws-toolkit

**Question: How do I fix the import statement in my test file?**

================================================

I run the following commands:

**commands to run up the tests**

```
cd cluster_health
python -m pytest tests/ -v -s
```

**I then get the following error!**

```
    ImportError while importing test module '<full path>...\cluster_health\tests\unit\test_handler.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests\unit\test_handler.py:5: in <module>
    from health_check import app
health_check\app.py:3: in <module>
    import my_elastic_search
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_elastic_search'
```

**.\cluster_health\tests\unit\test_handler.py**

```
import json
import sys
import pytest
import health_check
from health_check import app
from health_check import my_elastic_search
# from unittest.mock import patch
import mock
from mock import Mock

def test_lambda_handler(apigw_event, monkeypatch):
    CONN = Mock(return_value="banana")
    monkeypatch.setattr('health_check.my_elastic_search.connect', CONN)
    ret = app.lambda_handler(apigw_event, "")    
    # etc...
```

**.\cluster_health\health_check\app.py**

```
import json
import sys
import my_elastic_search

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(my_elastic_search.connect("myhost", "myuser", "mypass"))
    # etc
```

**.\cluster_health\health_check\my_elastic_search.py**

```
def connect(the_host, the_user, the_pass):
    return "You are connected!"
```

Comment: Do you have an init file?

Comment: is `<full path>` defined somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder) and  @woofless (above) here is my  solution to the problem (the problem statement really is that I am referencing a module in a parent directory.  The scaffolding for the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio with SAM does not provide the appropriate code to reference additional parent modules adequately)!

Note the **sys.path.insert** below. Additionally, as per @woofless I simplified my namespace reference so that it does not reference the root folder "health_check".  Voila!

**.\cluster_health\tests\unit\test_handler.py**

```
import sys, os, inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
parentdir = "%s\\health_check"%os.path.dirname(parentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)
print(parentdir)

import json

import pytest
import health_check
import app
import my_elastic_search
```

Answer (score 1):

health_check is the name of a folder. When importing in Python you do not name the folder. You would simply use `import my_elastic_search`. However, this will probably result in module not found. You can use a module called 'sys' to define where the program should search for modules being imported, or you could put the code in the same directory as the module.
You would use `from` when importing a specific function from a file or a class from the file.